Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy
html:
<button id="btnGG">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRBfdsfssdjgnqD5&s" id="icon-gg">
Đăng nhập bằng google
</button>

this is code javascript:
const btnLoginGG = document.getElementById('btnGG')

btnLoginGG.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login/get-acc')

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json()
            console.log(data)
        } else {
            console.error('Network response was not ok:', response.statusText)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error)
    }
})

this is code java:
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://127.0.0.1:5500")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
@GetMapping("/get-account")
    public Object getAcc(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        return token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("email");
    }
}

I'm having trouble coding the Google account login function and getting the following error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google'
(redirected from http://localhost:8080/login/get-acc') 

from origin http://127.0.0.1:5500'

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
when I set the request's mode to 'no-cors' there is an
error: net::ERR_ABORTED 403


your server at :8080 needs to send CORS headers

u need to set up cors - see my answer here

This question is similar to: Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try:
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login/get-acc', { });
It should work fine.
